# QGIS 2.8.2 Print Composer Attribute Sorting

Tags: qgis, sorting

I need to sort an attribute table added to the Print composer layout with Alphanumeric characters.
I understand this is not desirable but the field is for naming farm paddocks...hard to avoid that. How can I sort by alphanumerically?

[image]

Name:
paddock1 
paddock2
calf3a
calf3b
Feedpad1
1
2
3

Please note, I have searched and searched for an answer or idea before posting this.

Answer (score 1):

Setting in yout screenshot works fine (QGIS 2.18.3), after hitting `OK`, table is sorted alphanumerically (*symbols -> numbers -> text*).

[image]

If you need handle sorting (for example you want to show text first and than numbers), you can add more sorting rules, something like:

[image]